# Failed to connect mysql in centos 6.5

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-connect, centos6.5

I'm using php-mysql-apache in centos 6.5 system all requirements are exists, i think i can publish my html files in localhost but when i try to connect to mysql in php script. It doesn't appear and it shows mysql connection error.

```
# rpm -qa |grep php 
  php-pdo-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64
  php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64
  php-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64
  php-mysql-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64
  php-cli-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64
  php-ldap-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64  
# rpm -qa |grep mysql
  mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64
  mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch
  mysql-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64
  mysql-server-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64
  php-mysql-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64
```

I also checked my mysql password and username are correct i try to connect as below :

```
$connect= mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
if(!$connect){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL " ;
}
```

Also "dynamic extensions" part of php.ini file as below :

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
; ... or with a path:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/msql.so
;
; If you only provide the name of the extension, PHP will look for it in its
; default extension directory.
  extension=mysql.so
  extension=mysqli.so
;;;
; Note: packaged extension modules are now loaded via the .ini files
; found in the directory /etc/php.d; these are loaded by default.
;;;;
```

I added this lines by hand;

```
 extension=mysql.so
 extension=mysqli.so
```

So where is my fault can do you have idea for run my php script in localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `mysql_connect` as it is deprecated, use MySQLi or PDO to connect – it's really a pain, but check your Apache error log or enable PHP to show all errors in your scripts and it may help.